# How to make a frame for WinForm, C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, frame

I've been looking into changing the color of the border for the windows form and found out it's decided by windows, ok that makes sense, so then I see that people who have asked this question before are told to go here http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/ Looks like the site isn't usable at the moment. So would I have to make my own frame? If so where would I go to figure this, out? I'm using visual studio 2012.

Comment: Paint the border in the Paint event after making the Form DoubleBuffered. No resize problem here..

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new to C#, the paint event? I just googled it, is this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, that is (almost) right; as you will be probably subclass form overriding the OnPaint event is preferred. I have added an example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a form that draws its own border, can be resized and moved..:

```
public partial class BorderForm : Form
{
    public BorderForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        BorderColor = Color.DarkSlateGray;
    }


    private const int hWidth = 12;        // resize handle width
    private const int bWidth = 28;        // border width
    public Color BorderColor { get; set;  }

    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // draw the border..
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(BorderColor, bWidth)
             { Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset})
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, ClientRectangle);
        // now maybe draw a title text..

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }


    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
        }
    }


    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x84) // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
        {  
            Point pos = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
            pos = PointToClient(pos);

            bool isTop = pos.Y <= hWidth;
            bool isBottom = pos.Y >= ClientSize.Height - hWidth;
            bool isRight = pos.X >= ClientSize.Width - hWidth;
            bool isLeft = pos.X <= hWidth;

            m.Result = (IntPtr)1;

            if (isTop) m.Result = 
                       isLeft ? (IntPtr)13 : isRight ? (IntPtr)14 : (IntPtr)12;
            else if (isBottom) m.Result = 
                 isLeft ? (IntPtr)16 : isRight ? (IntPtr)17 : (IntPtr)15;
            else if (isLeft) m.Result = (IntPtr)10;  
            else if (isRight) m.Result = (IntPtr)11;

            if ( m.Result != (IntPtr)1) return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}
```

The [WM_NCHITTEST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs show you how to simulate hitting the control and resize boxes if you need those. You should paint them somehow as well, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wants to make custom winform. In this case, you may wanna not render the default windows. Draw your desired winform in photoshop and use it as a background in your application. The issue with this approach is that you will need to design your own minimize, maximize and close buttons.

You may use the [FormBorderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw8kes41(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it disappear.

Comment: Ok, sounds pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

It's REALLY involved, but if you want you can create your own Windows Forms library, that is don't use the Windows Form project at all.  Use the Windows GDI Documentation and PInvoke.Net to call into the GDI API functions for creating windows etc and design your own form system.

The specific section you want to look at is Window Functions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Would probably be easier to accomplish what you want in WPF though, it's more modern and you can probably more easily design/build what you want.

Another thing that's becoming more common to do is make it a Self Hosted Web App that runs on localhost and use The Chromium Embeded Framework so you basically make a web app that runs and looks like a windows program which makes it really easy to port your program to Linux and MacOS.

Comment: BY WPF you mean Windows Presentation Foundation, correct? Sorry just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes, WPF = Windows Presentation Foundation

Comment: Ok, So for changing the border look, should I go with what Mox said and design my winForm in photoshop and use it as my background?

Comment: If you do that the image will shrink and grow as the form is resized.  Perhaps a better method would be to design just the border in 4 pieces.  Make an image for the top border, left border, bottom border, and right border.  Then draw them on the top, left, right, and bottom.  That way they don't get messed up as the form resizes.  You could also do that in one image, and then copy out the individual pieces and draw the pieces (using concept like some websites use where they have multiple images in one file).

Comment: Right, Thanks for the help! I'm definitely going with this method.