# How to drag and resize in all four sides and corners in border-less Winform Application C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a windows form application in visual studio 2017. I have changed *FormBorderStyle* to *None*. I want to drag & resize in all four sides and corners. Please, help me. how to do it?.
I am not asking about this one
[How to make a frame for WinForm, C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097308/how-to-make-a-frame-for-winform-c)
.
In this, we can only resize from one right bottom corner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a frame for WinForm, C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097308/how-to-make-a-frame-for-winform-c)

Comment: @Idle_Mind In this, we can only resize from one corner. I am asking to resize from all four sides and corner.

Comment: I just posted the code from that link into a blank form.  It resizes on all edges and corners as expected.  The border is thick and ugly, but that can be removed by deleting the Paint() handler.  You must have implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Okay, You are right. sorry for having mistaken you.